# References books and lecture notes for Amenability

Tags: self-learning, amenability

I am reading the book "Lectures on amenability" by Volker Runde

I was wondering if someone could suggest me some books and Lecture notes with some good problems to go over

My backgrounds are the first course in Functional Analysis and a Banach algebra

Thanks for the help

Comment: What book did you use for functional analysis? Just to give us an idea I’d be level of knowledge and topics you have about the subject.

Comment: functional analysis and Infinite -Dimensional Geometry  by  mariab Fabin, peter Habala